# how to scale producers in kafkajs application using Apache Kafka and Nodejs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am building a central notification Engine for all micro services. I am using KafkaJs library. To scale consumer we can create multiple consumers. How do i scale producers in kafkajs? Can i create multiple producers in KafkaJs library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A producer is typically a single variable within any app and reused across functions

To scale producers you'd deploy multiple processes of the same producer app

Comment: i have read that we can use multipe producer or multiple producer threads. BDW what u mean by deploy multiple process. u mean the producer.js kafka file ? coz that just calls the kafka java api..

Comment: KafkaJS doesn't "call Java API", so not sure what you mean there, but yes, you'd typically run "producer.js" multiple times. You could also try to use threads, but it usually easier to do multiprocessing rather than multithreading

Comment: For creating multiple consumer we call the kafkajs library like this.
 const ordersConsumer = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'orders'});
    const paymentsConsumer = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'payments'});
    const notificationsConsumer = kafka.consumer({groupId: 'notifications'});
I want to know how to do that for producers. I have a notification app and for every customer i want to have a separate producer.

Comment: You can do the same for producers, if they need different configs. Or one producer can send messages to individual topics and there is no need to scale that within one application since you're only calling send function once per event